# Set Google Cloud connection in Airflow using env vars

Tags: airflow

How can you set Google Cloud / BigQuery connection parameters in Airflow by using Environment Variables; and so avoiding requiring logging into the UI or running a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the project is in the env var `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, you can set these

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEFAULT=;?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT=;?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
```

Ideally Airflow would allow a default project of `None`, and the underlying libraries would handle this

Comment: Thanks for this information! I assume both of these connections will use application-default connections for the GCP project... How would one reference a .json key-file using this syntax?

Comment: I'm didn't need to do that, but I think you should be able to use the same method - replace `project` with the relevant keyname